# Can you explain this double to string conversion behavior in C#?

Tags: c#, double, rounding, tostring

I'm trying to figure out why this happens and what is C# doing here.

Let's say we have a double: **277.3599853515625** (that's 13 digits after the period)

Then **277.3599853515625.ToString() -> "277.359985351563"**

We lost a digit and it looks like the number got rounded UP.

But **Math.Round(277.3599853515625,12) -> 277.359985351562** (looks like normal math rounding results in rounding DOWN)

I thought maybe if I give ToString() the formatting I want it would do the correct thing (give me the entire number):

**277.3599853515625.ToString("0.#############") -> "277.359985351563"** (that's 13 # signs, and still lost a digit and rounded UP)

If I reduce the last digit from 5 to 4, it rounds DOWN:

277.359985351562**4**.ToString("0.#############") -> "277.35998535156**2**"

So it is clearly doing the rounding, but the rounding rules are different from normal math rounding. My first thought was that it's just treating 5 different, when normal rounding rounds 5 down, the ToString rounds it up, but look at this:

277.359985351562**4999**.ToString("0.#############") -> "277.35998535156**3**" (WHAT?!?!?!?)

Do you have any idea what is happening here and what exactly C#'s logic in ToString() does?

The reason I'm asking is that I need to understand how to replicate the same behavior in a different language.

Thank you.

Comment: Well my first thought is that it's IEEE 754 standard fault not exactly the string fault. And the solution would be taking care of bits representing the number so that they stay the same across languages.

Comment: Have you considered floating point precision error - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Representable_numbers,_conversion_and_rounding?  You can try changing the value as a Decimal type - which has better decimal point precision.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic behavior of a tool that is written in C# and it looks like because of this ToString() behavior the tool is loosing/changing digits (implicitly). I have to be able to force the new tool to do the same thing, but for that I have to understand what ToString() is doing here exactly.

Comment: What language are you using for the new tool?

Comment: The new tool is in python

Comment: Just tried to find the cut-off point for rounding up or down:

(277.35998535156246).ToString() -> "277.359985351562"; (277.35998535156247).ToString() -> "277.359985351562";  (277.35998535156248).ToString() -> "277.359985351563";
(277.35998535156249).ToString() -> "277.359985351563"

Comment: What happens if you specify the Python float format as `%.15f`? That might be equivalent to the .NET 4.8 default format of `G15`.

Comment: Tried it, it rounds down, just like Math.Round() in C# does, but it's not what ToString() does.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   277.3599853515625.ToString() -> "277.359985351563"
   ```

   or

   ```
   277.3599853515624.ToString("0.#############") -> "277.359985351562"
   ```

   In this case, the `ToString` method is using `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` so that is why it converts 2 to 3 when the last digit is 5.
   For Reference, use this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0#system-midpointrounding-awayfromzero
2. ```
   Math.Round(277.3599853515625,12) -> 277.359985351562**
   ```

   In this case, `Math.Round` uses `MidpointRounding.ToEven` by default and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number. Need to explicitly define specific `MidpointRounding` if `ToEven` is not required.
   For Reference, use this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0
3. ```
   277.3599853515624999.ToString("0.#############") -> "277.359985351563"
   ```

   **(WHAT?!?!?!?)**

   Here, there are two concepts. One is that `ToString` considers this
   277.3599853515624999 as `Double` type, so it is a 16 digit number; that is why you are getting 16 digits.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(277.3599853515624999.GetType()); // System.Double;
   ```

   Double-15-16 digits (64 bit)

   ```
   Decimal -28-29 significant digits (128 bit)
   ```

   Thus, if change this (277.3599853515624999) to (277.3599853515624999**m**.ToString()),
   then you get 277.3599853515624999

   And the second one is that there is also rounding done by
   `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

You can play with the below code:

```
    Decimal h1=  277.3599853515624999m;
    string hh= "277.3599853515624999";
    string h = 277.3599853515624999m.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(277.3599853515624999.GetType()); // System.Double;
    Console.WriteLine(h);
    string hhh = Math.Round(277.345,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(hhh);
```

I hope now there is a clear picture.